# Magento, default theme. Category are not showing on the frontend

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I'm new in magento. Just installed CE and tried to add new category. 
It's active, has some products.
After that made cache reset. 
But frontend shows page without category.

So, how to make category visible for any page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [useful tips](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/top-3-solutions-when-your-magento-categories-are-not-displaying/) for solving this problem.

Comment: It works, here is the full link http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/top-3-solutions-when-your-magento-categories-are-not-displaying/